# Check if value exists In MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, row

I have a php variable: `$foo`

My MySQL table called `data` has the following structure:

```
id    var    header

1     zj3     http://google.com
```

I would like to check if `$foo` is all ready in `var` row.

If it is I would like to echo `header` ("http://google.com")

How would you approach this?

Thanks in advance, please ask if any clarification is needed!

Comment: So, you want to return a row if a value is NOT in the table?  I'm confused.

Comment: @Rocket Sorry for the HUGE typo!! Edited my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT `header` FROM `data` WHERE `var` = '$foo'
```

This will return all the headers with a `var` value of `$foo`.

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
if($query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `header` FROM `data` WHERE `var` = '$foo'")){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['header'];
  }
  mysqli_free_result($query);
}
```

Comment: So if I compare it to empty, I will know if the value exists? what will it return if it doesn't find any value?

Comment: If it doesn't find anything, it'll return nothing (`$query` will be `FALSE`).

Comment: @Trufa: What do you mean by 'So if I compare it to empty, I will know if the value exists'?

Comment: I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/xxx/public_html/xxx.com/index.php on line 11

Comment: Add another `)` before the `{` in the first line.

Comment: Seems I missed a `)`.  Should be ok now.

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters`, sorry to bother!!

Comment: @Rocket I am really sorrry I have to bother you again!! `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF`

Comment: Oops, missed a `;` after `$db=mysqli_connect`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you!!! (+1 :) ) It's working right now, but I'm getting a warning: `Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() [mysqli-result.fetch-assoc]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in` ideas, sorry for all the inconvenience!!

Comment: @Rocket any ideas on the warning? Again, sorry to bother!

Comment: Change `$query->fetch_assoc()` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`.  See updated answer.

Comment: @Rocket, I got a different one now: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() [function.mysqli-fetch-assoc]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in` I'm sorry I have to ask you everything, I have no idea what this errors mean, Thank you!!

Comment: `mysqli_free_result` should be outside the while loop.

Comment: @Rocket - Would hug you right now ;) All kidding aside, thanks for all your help and sorry for my ignorance!! Thanks again for the effort!

Comment: @Trufa: I'll take that hug.  It's ok, really, I'm here to help, and you're here to learn.

Comment: Should this be          if ( == )

Comment: @crh225: Actually, no.  I'm *not* comparing `$query` to `mysqli_query`.  I'm setting `$query` to `mysqli_query`, and checking the result of the assignment (`=`).  If `mysqli_query` returns `FALSE` the `if()` won't run, otherwise it would.

Comment: OK, I don't know why you people think this is correct but I tell you not only that is false but that is a dangerous answer...

Comment: @user3737190: The only dangerous thing is the lack of escaping.  This answer is 4 years old, so it's very out-of-date.  The current answer would be to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

first connect to the db

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT var, header FROM data WHERE id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    if($foo == $row['var']){
        echo $row['header'];
    }
}
```

EDIT: changed equality statement based on your edit

Comment: It says: "No database selected" why could this be?

Comment: @Trufa: You need to make sure you connect to the DB using `mysql_connect` first.

Answer (score 1):

are you asking if `$foo` matches *any* of the fields in `data`, or if `$foo=some_field`? Here for if you want `$foo==var`.

```
$foo='somevalue';
$query="SELECT id, var, header FROM `data` WHERE var='$foo'";
$result=mysqli_query($query);
if($result->num_rows==0) 
  $loc= 'http://google.com';//default value for when there is no row that matches $foo
}else{
  $row=$result->fetch_assoc(); //more than one row is useless since the first header('Location: x') command sends the browser to a new page and away from your script.
  $loc=$row['header'];

}
header ("Location: $loc);
exit;
```

ETA: since you've edited your question, it appears that you want to echo the header column if your search value matches your var column.  The above won't work for that.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, I want to echo the header column if your search value matches your var column.

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult at all, If I understand correctly then this should help you.

```
// Query Variable / Contains you database query information
$results = $query;

// Loop through like so if the results are returned as an array
foreach($results as $result)
{
    if(!$result['var'])
        echo $result['header'];
}

// Loop through like so if the results are returned as an object
foreach($results as $result)
{
    if(!$result->var)
        echo $result->header;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to know if $var's value is anywhere in that column (any row(s))?

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM data WHERE var = ?;
```

The result will be the number of rows for which the field var contains the value of $var.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template for all the "does it exist" questions.

This is the only thing that actually worked for me so far and is not deprecated.

```
if ($query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT header FROM data WHERE var = '$foo'")) {

        $header = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

        if ($header) {

            // The variable with value $foo exists.
        }
        else {

            // The variable with value $foo doesn't exist.
        }
    }
    else {

        // The query didn't execute for some reason. (Dammit Obama!)
    }
```

**WARNING!**

Even if the variable **DOES NOT EXIST** the comparison between **$query** and **mysqli_query()** will always return **TRUE**.

The only way --which happened to me-- for the comparison to return **FALSE** is because of a syntax error in your query.

I don't know why it worked for the guy who wrote the accepted answer, maybe it's an update or maybe he had a syntax error and was so confident that he didn't check if it could ever be **TRUE**.

Here's the comment someone made for correcting his syntax:

*"Add another ) before the { in the first line"*

***So, the accepted answer is WRONG!***